# Python html table layout

Tags: python, html, html-table

I'm using the `HTML.table` from [HTML.py](http://www.decalage.info/python/html). I have a list with this structure: `a = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]`. By using the HTML.table my table is only with one column but I want them to be two. How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like: `a = [['a', 'a2'], ['b', 'b2'], ['c', 'c2']]`

Your outer list makes the rows, the inner lists make the columns.

---

You can use `itertools` to regroup your lists:

```
import itertools
b = list(itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue='', *([itertools.chain(*a)] * 2)))
```

(sets `b` to `[('a', 'b'), ('c', '')]`)

That `2` is how many elements you want per sublist, i.e. how many columns you want in this case. `fillvalue` is the value it fills in when it runs out; default is `None`.

Comment: maybe most likely I have to do something like this: a = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']]
and then make it like this [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Added that to the answer.